# How to get data from the StreamBuilder into the GridView directly in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, gridview, stream-builder

Hello I'm setting a profile page and I'm trying to get the data from **Firestore**, so I set up a **StreamBuilder<List>** and gave it the stream to get the data but the problem is how to I use that data to display it into my **GridView**?

My code:

```
StreamBuilder<List<UserModel>>(
     stream: userProviderData.user,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       return GridView(
         gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
           crossAxisCount: 2,
           crossAxisSpacing: 10,
           mainAxisSpacing: 10,
         ),
         primary: false,
         shrinkWrap: true,
         children: [
           Text(
             'How Do I get the FullName here?' ?? fullNameOnNullText,
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(fontWeight: 
                 FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from the `StreamBuilder` by using the `.data` property of the snapshot in the builder.

And since your data is a list, you can map that into a list of child widgets in the `GridView`.

See below:

```
StreamBuilder<List<UserModel>>(
     stream: userProviderData.user,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       List<UserModel> userModelList = snapshot.data;

       return GridView(
         gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
           crossAxisCount: 2,
           crossAxisSpacing: 10,
           mainAxisSpacing: 10,
         ),
         primary: false,
         shrinkWrap: true,
         children: userModelList.map((UserModel userModel) =>
           Text(
             userModel.name,
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.copyWith(fontWeight: 
                 FontWeight.w600),)
           .toList()
  ,
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I managed to solve the problem after doing some experiments, I just moved the **StreamBuilder()** to the highest point of the tree inside the file, changed the **UserService()** from **List<UserModel>** to simply just **UserModel** and the way I called the data was simply by using **snapshot.data.fullName** also made a direct connection to the **UserService()** cuz for some reason when I connected it to the getter from the **BL** it returned **null**,  ```Stream<UserModel> get getCurrentUserData => userService.getCurrentUser();``` any idea how I may resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Before returning the widget, you should check first if the stream has finished loading.
After getting the data, the best way is to use `List<Widget>.generate()` for the child creation.

You can try this:

```dart
StreamBuilder<List<UserModel>>(
  stream: userProviderData.user,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) { // Check the status here
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return GridView(
      gridDelegate:
          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
      primary: false,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: List<Widget>.generate(
        snapshot.data.length, // same length as the data
        (index) => Text(
          snapshot.data[index].fullName, // Use the fullName property of each item
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .subtitle2
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I managed to solve the problem after doing some experiments, I just moved the **StreamBuilder()** to the highest point of the tree inside the file, changed the **UserService()** from **List<UserModel>** to simply just **UserModel** and the way I called the data was simply by using **snapshot.data.fullName** also made a direct connection to the **UserService()** cuz for some reason when I connected it to the getter from the **BL** it returned **null**,  ```Stream<UserModel> get getCurrentUserData => userService.getCurrentUser();``` any idea how I may resolve this?